# Jstree rename function doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, jstree

I'm using JStree library for building the tree control. Unfortunately, renaming the node doesn't work in Chrome (Version 48.0.2564.116 (64-bit))

It doesn't even work on a JStree website. When I try to rename the node, cursor disappears: [demo link](https://www.jstree.com/demo/)

Any hint is greatly appreciated

Comment: The official demo works for me in Chrome 48.0.2564.116 (32 bit) on Windows 7. But this could be a known issue: https://github.com/vakata/jstree/issues/1308

Comment: Thanks for this info